# How to add .mp3 files from NSBundle to NSArray in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsbundle

I have list of **.mp3** files in my Resources folder within an iOS 7.2 XCode project.I have add all .mp3 files in to one array,

Used Below code :

```
   NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@".mp3" inDirectory:@"Resources"];
```

However I am not getting any record in **NSArray**,What is wrong I did in above code, How to add my .mp3 files in to array if any one know please tell me.

Comment: Are you trying to add a file to any array, or this specific array?

Comment: @dokun1, Yes I want add .mp3 file in to one array, All file are available in NSBundle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Resources" folder won't actually exist in the app bundle. That's just a group in your Xcode project. And don't add the "." to the type.

Your line of code should be:

```
NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"mp3" inDirectory:nil];
```